# How to set minimum android version support in ionic +react + capacitor project?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-react

I don't know how to set the minimum version of android to support, the apk created works only in new versions of android and doesn't work on older ones, i am a web developer and never developed anything related to android before, should i install sdk platforms related to that version on android studio or there is a certain config to change in my development files???

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the latest Capacitor version (v4) you can set the minimum and target SDK version in `android/variables.gradle`.

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    ...
}
```

[Latest documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0#update-android-variables)

Answer (score -4):

you should set Target SDK version and Min SDK version, you can set it in your config.xml like this :

```
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="29" />
```

and you need to install SDK for sure , for example in the code that i've written you should have SDK 29 ( or any other SDK) .

Edit:

this Answer is for Cordova not Capacitor

Comment: `config.xml` is for cordova projects.